# owl carousel in bootstrap modal first time display all images and then owl-carousel work properly

Tags: owl-carousel

owl carousel in the bootstrap modal, when we open the modal first time, at a time display all images and then owl-carousel work properly.

[image]

then after work properly.

[image]

My code is,

**Model code,**

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="eduAppModal1" role="dialog"
     tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg modal-dialog-zoom" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content eduApp-modal">
            <div class="modal-body mb-0 p-0">
                <div class="row" id="eduAppCard1">                       
                    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7">
                        <div id="eduAppSlider1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme eduApp-slider">
                            <div class="item img-div">
                                <img id="eduAppSliderimg1" class="eduApp-slide-img img-fluid"
                                     src="frontend/images/slider/eduApp/eduApp_Academics_1.png"
                                     alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item img-div">
                                <img id="eduAppSliderimg2" class="eduApp-slide-img img-fluid"
                                     src="frontend/images/slider/eduApp/eduApp_Academics_2.png"
                                     alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item img-div">
                                <img id="eduAppSliderimg3" class="eduApp-slide-img img-fluid"
                                     src="frontend/images/slider/eduApp/eduApp_Academics_3.png"
                                     alt="">
                            </div>
```

...

**open model click on,**

```
<a href="#eduAppModal1" id="eduAppTopic1" data-toggle="modal"
               class="color-gray-darker c6 td-hover-none abc">
                <img src="{{ url('frontend/images/eduAcademics_405x341.png') }}" class="img-responsive zoom"/>
            </a>
```

**owl carousel method work on click .**

```
$(iValue).click(function () {
                $("#eduAppSlider1").owlCarousel({
                    loop: true,
                    slideSpeed: 100,
                    singleItem: true,
                    center: true,
                    items: 1,
                    margin: 0,
                    responsiveClass: true,
                    responsive: {
                        0: {
                            items: 1
                        },
                        600: {
                            items: 1
                        },
                        1000: {
                            items: 1
                        }
                    },

                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owl carousel takes time during initialization of the slider. What you can do is add a loader till everything loads successfully.

Add a loader and hide the slider `div` until all resources load, you can give a try like below

Add a div above your slider:

```
<div id="loader">Loading...</div>
```

And on window load ( i.e when all resources successfully load ):

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#yourSliderDiv").fadeIn();
});
```

Make sure you hide your slider `div`

```
<div id="yourSliderDiv" style="display: none">
```

Comment: @NIKUNJGADHIYA my pleasure.

Comment: Can you please explain the answer in briefly? I tried and it's not working properly. I still can see the alignment adjusting when page load.

Comment: @acmsohail Owl carousel takes time during the initialization of the slider. What you can do is add a loader till everything loads successfully. 

So as I mentioned in the answer you first need to add a loader div which will be used as a cover until all content loads. So when the whole content loads ( on load event ) you can then display the owl carousel.